# XSL to transform XML filtering out only element and attribute values?

Tags: xml, xslt, localization, xmldiff

I need to transform the following XML to XML that has the same elements and attributes except for values that can be localized - basically English phrases.

Some of the elements (`<footnote>`) and attributes are optional (`<display_data_type>`), and I'd like to be able to do this generically - without having a template for each element.  Is that possible?

The ultimate goal is to be able compare the default version of the XML with a localized version, ignoring the localized strings.

For example the following:

```
<data_schema>
    <field symbol="ACCOUNT" type="string" name="Account Number">
        <validators>
            <maxlength>6</maxlength>
        </validators>
        <description>The account number</description>
        <example>123456</example>
        <default_value></default_value>
    </field>
    <field symbol="POSTAL_CODE" type="string" name="Postal Code">
        <description>Postal Code for account</description>
        <example>22022</example>
        <footnote>Does not apply to certain accounts</footnote>
        <default_value></default_value>
    </field>
    <field symbol="DISCOUNT" type="string" name="Discount Percentage" display_data_type="percentage">
        <description>Descount determined by account</description>
        <example>1.5%</example>
        <default_value></default_value>
    </field>
</data_schema>
```

would be converted to:

```
<data_schema>
    <field symbol="ACCOUNT" type="string" name="">
        <validators>
            <maxlength>6</maxlength>
        </validators>
        <description/>
        <example/>
        <default_value/>
    </field>
    <field symbol="POSTAL_CODE" type="string" name="">
        <description/>
        <example/>
        <footnote/>
        <default_value/>
    </field>
    <field symbol="DISCOUNT" type="string" name="" display_data_type="percentage">
        <description/>
        <example/>
        <default_value/>
    </field>
</data_schema>
```

Comment: It doesn't matter for sake of the question which are localizable.  Any example which exludes any elements or attributes was acceptable.  And if it did matter, the example input and output which indicate which specific elements were localizable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example.  A template like this, when applied, should create a copy of the tree, minus the text areas and attribute text for attributes that are not symbol or type.

```
<xsl:template match="*">
  <xsl:element name="{name()}">
    <xsl:for-each select="@*">
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="name() = 'symbol' or name() = 'type'">
          <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <xsl:attribute name="{name()}"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:for-each>  

    <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Wrong. Clearly neither the answer poster nor the OP tested this solution.

Comment: Sean, you're incorrect - this works and is sufficient for my purposes.  Try again.

Comment: The output doesn't match the your listed expected output. In SO, when you ask a question and list some expected output, people take that to mean that that is a test for any proposed answers. If a proposed answer does not match the listed expected output, it is wrong. If the OP then says it is not wrong, then by definition the question is ambiguous. Question on SO need to fit the format as specified in the FAQ. Questions need to be specific, narrow and non-ambiguous. More...

Comment: Although not specified in the FAQ, in relation to XSLT, the top XSLT answerers will always require in addition, one use case (sample input plus expected output), XSLT version (1.0, 2.0 or 3.0), and if 1.0 then whether server-side or client-side.

Answer (score 4):

Here's another approach. This one builds upon the XSLT design pattern of the "Identity Transform" which as it basic just copies all nodes as-is.

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
   <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
   </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

You would extend this to add other template matches to match the nodes you want to take specific actions on, which in your case is to remove the text. The templates required would depend on the exact rules of the transformation.

Should you wish to remove text from specific elements and attributes, you would add the following two templates, to copy the nodes but without the text:

```
<xsl:template match="description|example|footnote|default_value">
   <xsl:copy/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@name">
   <xsl:attribute name="{name()}"/>
</xsl:template>
```

So, in this case the elements **description**, **example**, **footnote** and **default_value** have their text removed, along with the **@name** attribute. All other nodes would be copied as is, with their text.

On the otherhand, where you have a specific list of elements and attributes you want unchanged, you could add templates like so

```
<xsl:template match="field/*[not(self::validators)]">
   <xsl:copy/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@symbol|@type|@display_data_type">
   <xsl:copy/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@*">
   <xsl:attribute name="{name()}"/>
</xsl:template>
```

So, for the **validators** element, you are actually saying, remove everything that is not a **validators** element. The **validators** elements will be copied by the identity transform template. For the attributes, I have shown a slightly different approach where the attributes to keep have been explicitly listed, and you have a second template to remove the text from all others.

Here are the two full XSLTs in this case.

The first for removing text from specific nodes

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

   <xsl:template match="description|example|footnote|default_value">
      <xsl:copy/>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="@name">
      <xsl:attribute name="{name()}"/>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The second for keeping text in specific nodes

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

   <xsl:template match="field/*[not(self::validators)]">
      <xsl:copy/>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="@symbol|@type|@display_data_type">
      <xsl:copy/>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="@*">
      <xsl:attribute name="{name()}"/>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="node()">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

In the case of your sample document, both should produce the same output:

```
<data_schema>
   <field symbol="ACCOUNT" type="string" name="">
      <validators>
         <maxlength>6</maxlength>
      </validators>
      <description/>
      <example/>
      <default_value/>
   </field>
   <field symbol="POSTAL_CODE" type="string" name="">
      <description/>
      <example/>
      <footnote/>
      <default_value/>
   </field>
   <field symbol="DISCOUNT" type="string" name="" display_data_type="percentage">
      <description/>
      <example/>
      <default_value/>
   </field>
</data_schema>
```

Comment: Thanks Tim.  Very helpful explanation.  My main goal was simply to provide the most concise and understandable xslt, without having to provide a separate template for each localizable attribute/element.